# how to upgrade phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am running a [project](https://github.com/xaneem/flipbot)  when I am trying to run command

```
casperjs flipkart.js
```

then it is giving an error  `CasperJS needs at least PhantomJS v1.9 or later.`

`phantomjs --version`
1.8.2

`casperjs --version` 1.1.0

How I can upgrade the phantomjs ?

I am using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

run `sudo npm install phantomjs -g` it will install latest version of phantomjs globally in you system.

Here is a description of package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs

Comment: I try that but did not work for me. and finally I remove the phantomjs  and re install .

Comment: no I Just need greater then 1.9 and i gget now 1.9.7